# Wrong date picked by Datepicker component of Vue / Buefy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs2, buefy

I'm using Vue / Buefy as a datepicker in the form on my page (2nd step) https://waytorussia.net/Services/VisaSupport/Tourist.html

Sometimes only the date of birth gets picked wrongly: that is, the user selects 5th of June 1975 for example but then the data that gets recorded is the 6th of June 1975 or 4th of June 1975.

We thought the problem was on the server, so we made it so that the date picked is transferred as a string (to make sure there's no change) but now we think the problem is in Vue (especially that it's been reported that the datepicker component had this bug).

We tried changing

`getDate` to `getUTCDate` in the Datepicker component but this doesn't solve the issue.

Do you have any experience with it or do you know where to possibly look?

Comment: Making this comment so @AdamOrlov can remove the non-answer without repercussion: Does the issue goes only with 1 day +/- ? Couse if it does, then it looks to me like you have a trouble with a timezone.

Answer (score 2):

I added the date-formatter attribute as per the script below and it seems to be working fine.

```
<template>
    <b-field label="Select a date">
        <b-datepicker
            v-model="date"
            placeholder="Click to select..."
            icon="calendar-today"
            :date-formatter="formatter">
        </b-datepicker>
    </b-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'App',
    data() {
        return {
            date: new Date()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        formatter (d) {
            return d.toLocaleDateString()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Follow the example link:

https://codepen.io/jeanfsantos/pen/mKMBOv

I hope this helps you.